# Regular expression for finding image urls in <img> tag in HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What is the faster way to collect in an array srcs urls from image tag?

```
var result = [];
var html= '<img src="http://mysite.com/a/b/c/images/aaa.jpg"><img src="http://mysite.com/a/b/c/images/bbb.jpg"><img src="http://mysite.com/a/b/c/images/ccc.jpg">'
```

so the result should be in listed in the array as:

```
http://mysite.com/a/b/c/images/aaa.jpg
http://mysite.com/a/b/c/images/bbb.jpg
http://mysite.com/a/b/c/images/ccc.jpg
```

Comment: Can you guaraantee they'll all be in the exact same form?  I'm sure you're well awware that regex isn't suitably equipped for HTML parsing.  At any rate, in this form you could just match anything between quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to parse the string yourself:

```
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = html;
var imgs = tmp.getElementsByTagName('img'), l = imgs.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) result[i] = imgs[i].src;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
var result = [];
var html   = '<img src="http://mysite.com/a/b/c/images/aaa.jpg"><img src="http://mysite.com/a/b/c/images/bbb.jpg"><img src="http://mysite.com/a/b/c/images/ccc.jpg">';

$(html).each(function(){
  result.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Do you see a jQuery tag anywhere?

Comment: @Kolink Did you use regex ?

Comment: @GibboK Neither. See my answer for the best solution to this problem.